# Best method to add pagination to a gallery

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have clients website that is getting overloaded with images in his gallery. I was wondering if I could get some advice and see what you guys/girls think would be the best way to handle this current situation I'm in.

http://www.richsdockcompany.com/Gallery.php

This gallery is created by php and mysql. I would like to set a limit to 12 images then it would switch to a different page(s), but it can't refresh the page or else the gallery will reset.

**Current Code For Gallery**

```
<?php

include_once "header.php";
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/connections/dbconnect.php");
$images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
while ($image=mysql_fetch_assoc($images))
?>

<div id="Wrap">
<div class="Titles"><h2 style="font-size:36px;">Rich's Dock Company Image Gallery</h2></div><br />
<hr />
<div id="PhotoBoxWrap">

<!--======START GALLERY======-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column grid_12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column grid_12">
                    <!-- start Filter categories -->
                    <ul id="filter">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="shore">Dock Builders On Shore</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="commercial">Commercial Docks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="residential">Residential Docks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="repair">Dock Repairs &amp; Additions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="barge">Barge Life</a></li>                               
                    </ul>
                    <!-- End Filter categories -->  
                </div>
            </div>  

            <!-- Divider -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column grid_12">            
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="divider spacer5"></div>     
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End divider -->

<div class="row">

<ul id="stage" class="portfolio-4column">




<?php
$images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($image=mysql_fetch_array($images))
{
    ?>
    <li data-id="id-<?=$image["id"] ?>" data-type="<?=$image["data_type"] ?>">
    <div class="column grid_3 gallerybox">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="<?=$image["data_type"] ?>" href="images/gallery/<?=$image["file_name"] ?>" title="<?=$image["title"] ?>">
    <img src="images/gallery/<?=$image["file_name"] ?>" alt="<?=$image["title"] ?>" class="max-img-border"></a>
    <h4 style="color:#2B368D; text-align:center;"><?=$image["title"] ?></h4>
    <p style="text-align:center; font-size:15px;"><?=$image["description"] ?></p>
    </div>  
    </li>
    <?php
}
?>

</ul><!--END LIST-->
```

The only thing I can think of off the top of my head would be to create a slider that would contain all the images or use ajax with pagination so there would be no refresh problem.

I have never attempted pagination so please go easy on me here.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a db where the filenames are stored or is this gallery using only the filsystem and reads the folder where the images are stored?

Answer (score 1):

look at this example code, which handles the pagination in a simple way.
You can reuse the function getPagesNavi for every list which should be paginated.
It returns the html with the links to navigate through the pages.

If you like to load the pages with ajax you need to do some modifications by yourself. This is only an example to show you how it could work.

```
$page = intval($_GET['page']);
$myurl = 'index.php?action=list';

$db->select("select * from tablename");
$count_total = $db->getRecords();

$items_per_page = 10;
$start = $page * $items_per_page;
$limit = "limit $start, $items_per_page";

$db->select("select * from tablename $limit");

while($row = $db->fetchArray()) {
    // your output here...
}

echo getPageNavi($myurl,$page,$count_total,$items_per_page);


function getPagesNavi($link, $current_page, $count_total, $items_per_page, $number_of_visible_pagelinks_updown = 5, $page_varname = "page") {
    $result = "";
    if ($count_total <= 0) {
        return "";
    }
    $pages_float = $count_total / $items_per_page;
    $number_of_pages = ceil($pages_float) - 1;
    $start = $current_page - $number_of_visible_pagelinks_updown;
    $end = $current_page + $number_of_visible_pagelinks_updown;
    if ($end > $number_of_pages) {
        $dif = -$number_of_pages + $end;
        $end = $number_of_pages;
        $start = $start - $dif;
    }
    if ($start < 0) {
        $dif = -$start;
        $end = $end + $dif;
        $start = 0;
    }
    if ($end > $number_of_pages) {
        $end = $number_of_pages;
    }
    $back = $current_page - 1;
    $forward = $current_page + 1;
    if ($current_page > 0) {
        $result .= "
          <span class=\"pageItem\"><a href=\"$link&$page_varname=0\"><<</a></span>
          <span class=\"pageItem\"><a href=\"$link&$page_varname=$back\"><</a></span>";
    } else {
        $result .= "<span class=\"pageItem\"><<</span>";
        $result .= "<span class=\"pageItem\"><</span>";
    }
    for ($i = floor($start); $i <= floor($end); $i++) {
        $j = $i + 1;
        $class = "";
        if ($i == $current_page) {
            $class = " currentPageItem";
        } 
        $result.= "<span class=\"pageItem$class\"><a href=\"$link&$page_varname=$i\">$j</a></span>";
    }
    if ($current_page != $number_of_pages) {
        $result .= "<span class=\"pageItem\"><a href=\"$link&$page_varname=$forward\">></a></span>";
        $result .= "<span class=\"pageItem\"><a href=\"$link&$page_varname=$number_of_pages\">>></a></span>";
    } else {
        $result .= "<span class=\"pageItem\">></span>";
        $result .= "<span class=\"pageItem\">>></span>";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I have a db where the filenames are stored, but the images are pulled from a dir on the ftp. I will try this code out and get back to you. Thanks for the help.